# how to add object to a list in a view?

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed view where I have a form. I display values of a Contact (object) in Textboxes. The contact has a list of functions. I have also a list of all the functions that exist in database. In the view I'm listing all the functions by displaying checkboxes (value : Id of the function, display : name of the function). Before that,  I compare the list of the Contact's functions to all to functions and I checked those of the contact. Like that :

```
 @foreach (extranetClient.Models.Classes.FonctionContact fonction in ViewBag.Fonctions)
         {
                string coche = "";
                if ((@Model.ListeFonctions).Where(c => c.IdFonction == fonction.IdFonction).Count() > 0)
                     {
                          coche = "checked";
                     }

                <input type="checkbox" @coche id="@fonction.IdFonction" />@fonction.LibelleFonction <br />
         }
```

It looks like that:

[image]

But now, if the user checks a checkbox to add a function to the contact, I need to save it in the contact's list. I cannot find how to do that. Somebody has idea ?

Answer (score 1):

First we need to modify your checkboxes so they will post properly. When a checkbox is checked it will be posted like this `name=value`. But we want all your checkboxes to be posted into a collection, so the name will follow this format `function[x]` where x is an index of the checkbox. The value then becomes the ID of the function.

```
@{
    var i = 0;
}
@foreach (extranetClient.Models.Classes.FonctionContact fonction in ViewBag.Fonctions)
{
    string coche = "";
    if ((@Model.ListeFonctions).Any(c => c.IdFonction == fonction.IdFonction))
    {
        coche = "checked";
    }

    <input type="checkbox" @coche id="functions[@(i++)]" value="@fonction.IdFonction" />@fonction.LibelleFonction <br />
}
```

Now create an action method which can receive the checkboxes's data. Simply provide a parameter which can recieve an enumeration of `int` assuming your function IDs are `int`s.

```
public ActionResult UpdateFunctions(IEnumerable<int> functions)
{
    // TODO: functions contains IDs of all checked boxes.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: OK well, but it's a whole form and when we're submitting it, we receive all datas in a functions `public ActionResult AjouterModifierContact(Contact contactAModifier)
        {}`

Comment: If your posting into a model, just make sure the model can receive an enumeration of `int`, and name the checkboxes (`function[x]`) to that property on your model.

Comment: I'll try, I'll give you feedback about that. Thanks